# What do "yes" and "no" mean as responses to "are you aware of any contract or agreement"?

Tags: meaning

I am applying for a job and ran into this yes/no question. I don't fully understand it!

> To the best of your knowledge and belief, are you aware of any contract or agreement with your current employer (or other company), such as a non-competition or non-disclosure agreement, that impact or interfere with your ability to work for the Company?

if I answer "yes" ~ That means I am aware of any contact and there isn't any. (OR) "No" ~ which means I am not aware of any contract and there might be one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yes" would mean "I am aware of an agreement with my current employer that interferes with my ability to work for the Company."

Answering "Yes" could be a big problem.

You can't be aware of a contract that doesn't exist.

If you believe that no such agreement exists you would answer: "No.  I'm not aware of any such agreement."

If you are "certain" that no agreement exists then you still answer "No" because you are certainly not aware of such an agreement.

There might be an agreement with your current employer that you believe does not interfere.  Then you can also answer "No"

Comment: Thank you so much James

Answer (score 0):

No, to "be aware of any" means there is one, not that there are none. "Any" in English is not a word of negation. You can replace it with "a" or "one" in these sentences for a similar meaning.